# Flask error 500 handling: failed render template

Tags: python, error-handling, flask

I would like to handle database crash when my Flask application started. I created `@app.errorhandler(500)` where I want return `render_template`. At this moment database is unavailable. And `render_template` also fails. I do not know why. Any ideas?

```
Exception in rendering template: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2014 17:23:04] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1410, in handle_exception
    return handler(e)
  File "D:\proj\beardev\mcp\common\routes.py", line 101, in page_error
    raise ex
AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Could you show us sample code?

Comment: please include the full handler